# SQL server - execute scalar function without specifing db name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a user defined SQL function that I am able to call from management studio using syntax `dbo.Function(arg)`

Now, when I have to call this function from C# if I don't specify `**dbname**.dbo.Function(arg)` I get an error that SQL server does not find this user defined function. How can I solve this without specifing dbname ? I already connect to the server using a connection string that specifies the "`initial catalog =  dbname"`

---

It seems that I cannot reproduce mentioned behavior at this point :-) (either using SQL server 2005 or 2008) I have to put this question on hold

Comment: Could you show C# code and exact exception?

Comment: You may need to grant `EXEC` permissions on the function to the login used by your application.

Comment: @MartinSmith I use Windows Authetication in both management studio (where it works) and C# code. As I've said if I add in code also dbname ( e.g. SELECT
  DATEPART(YEAR, Activitylogs.Datastamp) AS YEAR_VALUE, dbname.dbo.ISOweek(Activitylogs.Datastamp) ... it works

Comment: Using a `SqlCommand` with command text `select dbo.Function()` works for me.

Comment: It is possible that I saw this only intermittent. I will have to put the question on hold because it seems to work now. Thank you all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string needs to specify the database to use initially. It might look something like this:

```
var cn = new SqlConnection(
    "SERVER=SomeServer;DATABASE=SomeDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
);
```

Without that, you're probably being dumped into the `master` database, which is why you need to fully qualify the function name.